# XCode: Project Files no longer linked with project/storyboard

Tags: xcode

Recently, some revision was done to one of my projects and the project had to be re-imported from SVN. All of the files are there, but I get weird issues when trying to use some of the project files.

For example, when selecting a view in IB, the assistant view would automatically show the associated header file for that view. Now, there is nothing under the 'Automatic' tab in the assistant view.

Also, when trying to #import certain files and create instances of them, xcode returns the error `Unknown type name`

Comment: Are the files red in the file browser?

Comment: Nope. They appear normally.

Comment: If you "Show in Finder" a file from Xcode, does it pull up the correct location?

Comment: Yes, it shows up just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have resolve the issue. I had to create a new .h and .m file and copy the contents of the old .h and .m into the new one. Once I set the view in storyboard to use this file I no longer received any errors.